# How to get the CPU time and consumption for a python application?

Tags: python, embedded, cpu

I'd like to profile the CPU time and CPU consumption of a python application on an embedded device. The ideal would be to have something similar to `resource_memory` in that you can directly enter a command in the prompt shell. I could read a lot about `psutil` and some other libs but the truth is I am running out of time and can't spend too much time learning how to make it work or add it to my application's code. So this isn't the ideal, it's overly complicated for what I need I believe. Also I don't want to have a line-by-line analysis, I just want the overall values of CPU consumption an use time during one run.

Is there something that matches my needs that someone could recommend to me ? Thank you!

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you want to profile CPU consumption of Python Application or from Python Application?

Comment: I want to know what are the CPU time and consumption used by my python app while it's running. Is it clearer ?